# ESC/POS Thermal Printer command to get the printer settings printed

Tags: thermal-printer, escpos

### Question:

Is there an ESC/POS command to send to a thermal printer in order to make it print its current settings?

### Context:

I have an **EPSON TM-T70II** thermal printer and I need help as I couldn't find anything helpful anywhere.

I am able to access the printer's **SELF-TEST** mode by switching it off and on and immediately holding the feed button pressed for 5-6 seconds.

If I long press the feed button again, it continues to the mode Selection where it prints some options for me to select. Selection is made by pressing the feed button as many times as a specific option needs and then long pressing it for 1 second.

These options are:

**0.** Exit and Reboot Printer

**1.** NV Graphics Information

**2.** Receipt Enhancement Information

**3.** Customize Value Settings

**4.** or more: None

Choosing **3** gets me to a set of selections and among them is: ***1.** Print Current Settings.*

Choosing this prints a somewhat long paper with all the printer settings.

This is exactly what i want to make the printer print but instead of making the whole multi-press & long-press procedure, i want to do it just by sending it a command through code.

Comment: The ESCPOS documentation lists all the commands supported by your printer: https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=324

Comment: @Joe thanks for answering. I've gone through that documentation multiple times but can't find a solution. So I guess the only way to print the current settings is manually. (?)

Comment: You're probably right.  Unless a command such as "Execute test print" happens to print what you want as part of its test print, the only other approach I could think of would be to experiment with "Transmit..." commands such as "Transmit the customized setting values" to collect the data you want to print; then print it yourself.